# firestore - listen to update on the entire collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using google's firestore and I want to get a live update on the entire collection.

I saw this in the documents:
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/CollectionReference#onSnapshot

but as far as I understood I have to get a document or to query a range of documents.

how can I listen to changes in the entire collection?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you refer back to the [Listen to multiple documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection) documentation, simply omit the where filter and you should get the whole collection.

The first line would look like this: `var query = db.collection("cities");`

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I was sure that `.onSnapshot` will work only on a query reference and not on collection reference

Answer (score 8):

From my current experience, `.onSnapshot` without query (`.where`) helps you listen to the whole collection. E.g

```
   db.collection('cities')..onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
      var cities = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          cities.push(doc.data().name);
      });
      console.log("Current cities in CA: ", cities.join(", "));
    });
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

You can read more there too.

Comment: The syntax has been updated to: `_db.collection(collectionKey).snapshots()`

Answer (score 0):

Heres the v9 way of listening to a whole collection:

```
const db = getFirestore();
const unsub = onSnapshot(collection(db, "cities"), (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
  });
});
```