# Get realtime updates with Cloud Firestore on entire collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I tried following this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48606611/firestore-listen-to-update-on-the-entire-collection) but I'm still unable to log the data.

**Question:**
 How do I unwrap the data of all docs of a collection?

Snippet:

```
return await db.collection("articles")
    .onSnapshot((docs) => {
      console.log("Docs data: ", docs.map(doc => doc.data()); // wont work
    });
```

Comment: What does a log or debugger indicate you are getting in `docs`, prior to anything else you do with it?  FYI onSnapshot doesn't return a promise, so it doesn't make sense to await it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you listen to an entire collection, you get a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot). You need to loop over that to get the individual documents:

```
return await db.collection("articles")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log("Docs data: ", doc.data());
      })
    });
```

---

*Update* I now see that you're accessing `docs` as if it's an array. The document array is in a `docs` property under the query snapshot, so:

```
return await db.collection("articles")
    .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      console.log("Docs data: ", querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()); 
    })
```