# How to listen to changes in Firebase database collection?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code:

```
someDocumentRef.collection("data").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            RelativeLayout emptyLayout = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.empty_layout);
            if (task.getResult() == null || task.getResult().isEmpty()) {
                emptyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                Map<Character,List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> dataDoc = new HashMap<>();
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    char letter = getFirstLetter(document.getString("full_name"));
                    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> l = dataDoc.get(letter);
                    if (l == null) {
                        l = new ArrayList<>();
                        l.add(document);
                        dataDoc.put(letter, l);
                    } else {
                        l.add(document);
                    }
                }

                // Create recycler view
                emptyLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adapter = new DataAdapter(getActivity(), dataDoc);
                rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In my `onCreateView` method (Fragment). Basically, it gets all documents from the collection `data` of the Firebase database and passes it to the adapter in order to create a recycler view. Works great but my question is how to listen to changes in the database and once some new document inserted or removed, update the recycler view? Note that I don't use the `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` adapter, rather my custom adapter. Also, I'm using Firebase Cloud database.

Comment: Use addOnValueChangeListener which have the onDataChange method returning a datasnapshot. So when ever your database gets updated, there's that listener that always listen. Then add a method in adapter to receive the new data

Comment: So it's not possible to have a listener on a collection? If I set a listener for each document, how can I update the RV?

Comment: Sorry I was talking about Realtime database not fire store. But I'm not sure firestore is realtime, I've not used it, I'll suggest you switch to realtime database

Comment: @Jason Unfortunately I can't. I'll wait if someone else have an idea. Thank you.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually listen to changes in firebase, sorry for the earlier comment. I checked fire store documentations and I saw this

```
final DocumentReference docRef = 
db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.addSnapshotListener(new 
 EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
  @Override
  public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot 
 snapshot,
                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
    if (e != null) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
        return;
    }

    if (snapshot != null && snapshot.exists()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: " + snapshot.getData());
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
      }
   }
 });
```

Referenced from  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

I hope it helps

**Edit** 
To listen to the whole collection:

```
    db.collection("cities")
    .addSnapshotListener(new 
     EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value,
                            @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) 
           {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
                return;
            }

            List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                if (doc.get("name") != null) {
                    cities.add(doc.getString("name"));
                }
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Current cites in CA: " + cities);
        }
      });
```

This will definitely listen to the whole collection.
Reference:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48608816/8714139

**Edit**  this how you'll get ur values

```
        Map<Character,List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> dataDoc = new HashMap<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : value) {
                char letter = getFirstLetter(document.getString("full_name"));
                List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> l = dataDoc.get(letter);
                if (l == null) {
                    l = new ArrayList<>();
                    l.add(document);
                    dataDoc.put(letter, l);
                } else {
                    l.add(document);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know that I can listen to specific document, but it does not help much if new document was added to the collection. In that scenario I want to add it to the recycleview (even if I'll have to remove it all and set it again). If it was possible to listen to a collection (instead to a document) I could just remove the RV and set it again. I'm sure there is a way to do it but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: oh that's looks great! As I understand from other topic, in order to update the RV I need to change `dataDoc`. I moved it to be as a field of the main fragment. Now I'm trying to update it. But what is `QuerySnapshot`? How do I convert it to `QueryDocumentSnapshot`? Updated my question so it will be more clear.

Comment: If you check my editted code you'll see:     
 List<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : value) {
                if (doc.get("name") != null) {
                    cities.add(doc.getString("name"));
                }
            } value is QuerySnapshot which you'll have to loop.