# Organizing multiple firebase triggers

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have multiple firebase triggers organized as follows:

Function1.ts:

```
    exports.fileupload = db.collection("/x").onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
       snap.docChanges().forEach((change) => {//something}) 
    });
```

Function2.ts:

```
    exports.something = db.collection("/y").onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
       snap.docChanges().forEach((change) => {//something})
    });
```

Then in index.ts:

```
const ai = require("./Function1");
const users = require("./Function2");

exports.fileupload = ai.fileupload ;
exports.something = users.something;
```

This causes the `Function1.ts` function to trigger multiple times when a new document is added. If I don't export them from index.ts as well then it triggers only once but then any firebase auth functions don't trigger at all. Is there a better way to organise this?

I understand that triggers can trigger multiple times for the same event, but I also can't find the eventId for `onSnapshot` as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions)

What causes this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any database triggers in your code at all.  You have two snapshot query listeners defined, but they are not triggers as you see in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).  If you had a Firestore trigger, it would look like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('my-collection/{docId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => { /* ... */ });
```

If you define snapshot listeners at the top level of your code, they will execute exactly once **for each server instance that is allocated** to run any other actual trigger that happens.  Any number of server instances can be allocated, based on the load applied to your function.

Since we can't see any of the code that actually defines the trigger, we can't fully understand what's going on here.  But it's generally safe to say that long-running snapshot listeners are not appropriate for Cloud Functions code, which is stateless in nature.  If you want to query the database in a trigger, you should use a `get()` instead of a listener.

Comment: Thank you Doug, I edited my question. Also I didn't know they are not triggers because they do execute every time something changes (see updated code above). What you call snapshot query listeners do trigger when there is a change in a specific collection (in my case I only monitor when someone adds something). Perhaps this is not the right way to go about this then?

Comment: To be more specific: I've used this solution by also checking what the type of change is (added in this case) https://stackoverflow.com/a/59298021/4487530

Comment: Also something important - I'm using the admin SDK:)